# Blurred bitmap/embedded text when scrolling in TextField? (Flash/AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield, flash, flashdevelop

Basically, if I leave the text as-is, I get this:

[image: Screen grab]

As you can see, there is more text overflowing, so if I hit <kbd>END</kbd> on my keyboard, it does what TextField usually does and moves to the end with a little extra gap to show as such. Only, in this case the text is blurred:

[image: Screen grab 2]

Why is this happening?

Here is the embedded custom font:

```
[Embed(source = "../../../assets/font/FleftexYC_bold.ttf", 
    fontFamily      = "FleftexYC", 
    fontStyle       = "normal", // normal|italic
    fontWeight      = "bold",  // normal|bold
    unicodeRange    = "U+0020-007E,U+00A3", 
    embedAsCFF      = "false"
)]
private static const _FleftexYC_bold:Class;
```

And here is the actual TextField code:

```
this._textField = new TextField();
this._textField.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("FleftexYC", 8, 0x000000, true);
this._textField.embedFonts = true;
this._textField.height = 13;
this._textField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
this._textField.x = 9;
this._textField.y = 7;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
_textField.antiAliasType=flash.text.AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
_textField.gridFitType=flash.text.GridFitType.PIXEL;
```

[The manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#gridFitType) says this makes your text field align its display with pixel grid of the monitor, meaning that pressing "End" will not result in a blur anymore.

Comment: That worked great! It has a little noticeable anti-aliasing when you highlight text but I can totally live with that. Thanks!