# Letter keys blurred on custom keyboard while Special keys super crisp

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, text-rendering

I am a linguist, not a programmer. With the help of an example, a few books and this forum I have created a custom keyboard for a minority language and have manged to turn the background from ugly black to custom colours.

Now I noticed that the letter keys (like "a", "ǝ", "b") on the keyboard are looking blurred. And I only noticed because the symbols on the "special keys" are super crisp looking. So please see my screenshot below:

I have not done any tricks to the "text" on the keys. I have not provided a special font; I guess my keyboard-app is applying a default system font like Noto. For this language, all the "special characters" like ɖ, Ɖ, ŋ, Ŋ, ǝ, Ǝ, ɛ, Ɛ, ɩ, Ɩ, ɔ, Ɔ, ʊ, Ʊ are available, they render fine (only blurred). I list them here to show why this language does need a custom keyboard. This question is relevant to (just) several thousand WhatsApp and Facebook and Android users.

Here is a screenshot from a "normal" phone: No special system font, no rooting, normal Android 6.0, screen resolution 1280 x 720, screenshot taken by the inbuilt tool and then scaled to 400% for you in GIMP (without any interpolation of course) and saved as lossless PNG.

Please note how the "special symbols" have some reasonable anti-aliasing where needed (round corners and diagonals) and how the vertical downstrokes on "ŋ", "q" and "1" show that there is **un-needed anti-aliasing(?) applied to all the letters**. This behaviour is consistent over the entire keyboard: **all** letters are **blurred**, while **all** the symbols are **crisp**.

[image: screenshot scaled to 400%]

I can reproduce this problem on several different phones (real hardware), for example on an Android 4.4.2 with 800 x 480 px Screen it looks even worse.

Update 1: From a user comment I was prompted to go and have another look at my "special characters" like caps-lock and keyboard-hide (as shown in screenshot). I was surprised to find that those are just png-files and I have many of those in the drawable-subfolders like drawable-xhdpi in 24x24px up to 96x96px. I got them from some public Google-set-of-icons many weeks ago. So it seems if I take the trouble to make crisp png-images for each of my 4 x 39 keys for each of the 6 different screen-sizes (936 files for those readers who cannot move one before figuring this out) then I would have at least a brute-force work-around, but not really an answer to the "where and why the evil blurr?".

"Going bitmap" in an Android-world where the first phones (I believe from Android 8 it is available) are finally getting vector-drawables does not feel right. Who knows, there might be screens out there which will go zombie on those 24x24px or 96x96px PNGs and will render even worse than what I see on my hardware... :1 etadpU

Now I will give my data, and please shout if you want to look at more.

From my file **\app\src\main\res\xml\qwerty.xml** I give you the lines that show up in the screenshot plus the intro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
>


<Row>
    <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="331" android:keyLabel="ŋ" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template" android:popupCharacters="ŋɲ"/>
    <Key android:codes="99,231" android:keyLabel="c" android:popupCharacters="cç©" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"/>
...
</Row>

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_capslock_black_24"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" android:isModifier="true"
            android:isSticky="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q"/>
...   
</Row>

<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key android:codes="-3" android:keyIcon="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_hide_black_24"
            android:keyWidth="15%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="123" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>

</Row>
```

And here is my **\app\src\main\res\layout\input.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<org.gasana.android.aniikeyboard.LatinKeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground"
    android:keyTextColor="#000000"
    android:popupLayout="@layout/popup"
/>
```

My background is not a bitmap but xml-defined, here is the "normal" (not pressed) file  **\app\src\main\res\drawable\normal.xml** which you see applied in the screenshot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#A1B7F7" />
    <solid android:color="#C7D4FA"/>
</shape>
```

I have seen in this other question, that blurring can be related to anti-alias and aligning. So now I need help please to check whether this is my problem in the Android-Context, and where it is happening and how i can fix it:

[Blurred bitmap/embedded text when scrolling in TextField? (Flash/AS3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687207/blurred-bitmap-embedded-text-when-scrolling-in-textfield-flash-as3)

I am ready to quote more code and answer your follow-up questions. Please help me to get closer to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with developing custom keyboards, just one thing I noticed -- the crisp looking keys have a keyIcon assigned to them, which is (probably) a vector drawable. But I do not assume you'd have to provide an icon for every normal key, so this observation may be of limited use and helpfulness.

Comment: @Ridcully Oops, I almost lied to you (and had to delete my first reply). I looked it up, trying to edit my question and wanting to show an example of one of the "special character vector files". And I was surprised to find it is just a humble png-file. Will edit my question. This was helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. However, I do not think it should be necessary to provide a drawable for every key ... also, are the popup characters also rendered blurry? Because for those, I think you cannot even provide drawables.

Comment: @Ridcully I just checked again: Yes, the popups are also blurred. Did not measure but at naked eye looks the same. No surprise to me, as they are probably rendered through the same technology.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with KeyboardView. I think it might help in this case too, with the **LatinKeyboardView**.

In my case, I added shadowRadius to the **KeyboardView** attributes

**android:shadowRadius="0.0"**

[KeyboardView: android:shadowRadius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNMVU.png)

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I will have a look as soon as I find time - just moved overseas, so crazy busy. If this helps, I will give feedback here.